# Golang concurrent writes to multiple files

Tags: go, concurrency

I need to write multiple file at the same time, however I have this weird behavior where the time taken to write is increasing when too many concurrent go routine are executed.
I'm reproducing this behavior with this code sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mu sync.Mutex

func WriteToFile(data []byte, fileName string) error {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(fileName, data, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func GenerateFile(index int) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    start := time.Now()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    buf := make([]byte, 7500000)
    rand.Read(buf) // generate random data
    randomFileName := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/gotest-%v", rand.Int())
    err := WriteToFile(buf, randomFileName)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.Remove(randomFileName)
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("goroutine id: %v, generate file %s done in %s", index, randomFileName, elapsed)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go GenerateFile(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("done in %s", elapsed)
}
```

I get the following output:

```
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-6971393788758345733 done in 11.900753ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-4673598773814253679 done in 19.610377ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-4521113305882394455 done in 30.778525ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-8353995959628873274 done in 44.008548ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-1525622757191165040 done in 54.167972ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-5591269383853180110 done in 62.932048ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-6764721932990560969 done in 69.798237ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-2295272693261924206 done in 78.44878ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-2676611775321001319 done in 87.014884ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-3509686945670964049 done in 96.566297ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-4836444971131413206 done in 105.83336ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-1300813662850892446 done in 114.375852ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-8820441258575272048 done in 123.49409ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-4521621037307893446 done in 131.889565ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-3672417531832062779 done in 141.114569ms
2022/09/29 15:56:42 generate file /tmp/gotest-1086595338191073308 done in 150.002702ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-3614980454862600779 done in 159.816332ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-8835923576403879976 done in 168.48278ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-234153523891197266 done in 177.340838ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-4694585587220869374 done in 185.675593ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-790814872699550686 done in 194.672799ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-1109155725008951319 done in 203.573936ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-2107324352293381651 done in 212.619876ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-2262414210446865118 done in 221.291951ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-5425047562930316945 done in 230.636649ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-5121293724555456542 done in 239.258288ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-8761336775543022197 done in 247.899475ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-3896102679035637543 done in 259.054695ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-6219168972567815878 done in 266.248078ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 generate file /tmp/gotest-8075914412323098705 done in 275.679818ms
2022/09/29 15:56:43 done in 276.64278ms
```

I would expect that all the requests should be done roughly at the same time, since I'm starting goroutines,  and would take as much time than the first goroutine. If I remove the data generation and file writing parts, requests comes back at the same time. Also I did experiment with worker pool, but the overall time is still increasing if I add too many workers.

I don't understand this behavior. Could someone give me an explanation ?

Edit: Also is there a solution to increase parallel file writing in Go ?

Edit2: I tried by pregenerating data before writing it to disk, and using very small byte slice (5) and the behaviour is still the same.

Edit3:
Ok so I don't understand all the details but I suppose it's related to the golang scheduler and the way [it handles syscalls](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/GoSchedulerAndSyscalls).
Based on worker pool and job queue described in [this article](http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/), I updated my example and got consistent results to write files.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

var (
    MaxWorker = 2
    wg        sync.WaitGroup
)

// Job represents the job to be run
type Job struct {
    FileIndex int
}

// A buffered channel that we can send work requests on.
var JobQueue chan Job

func GenerateFile(index int) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    start := time.Now()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    data := make([]byte, 7500000)
    rand.Read(data) // generate random data
    randomFileName := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/gotest-%v", rand.Int())
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(randomFileName, data, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.Remove(randomFileName)
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("goroutine id: %v, generate file %s done in %s", index, randomFileName, elapsed)
    return nil
}

// Worker represents the worker that executes the job
type Worker struct {
    WorkerPool chan chan Job
    JobChannel chan Job
    quit       chan bool
}

func NewWorker(workerPool chan chan Job) Worker {
    return Worker{
        WorkerPool: workerPool,
        JobChannel: make(chan Job),
        quit:       make(chan bool)}
}

// Start method starts the run loop for the worker, listening for a quit channel in
// case we need to stop it
func (w Worker) Start() {
    go func() {
        for {
            // register the current worker into the worker queue.
            w.WorkerPool <- w.JobChannel

            select {
            case job := <-w.JobChannel:
                GenerateFile(job.FileIndex)
            case <-w.quit:
                // we have received a signal to stop
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

// Stop signals the worker to stop listening for work requests.
func (w Worker) Stop() {
    go func() {
        w.quit <- true
    }()
}

type Dispatcher struct {
    // A pool of workers channels that are registered with the dispatcher
    WorkerPool chan chan Job
    MaxWorkers int
}

func NewDispatcher(maxWorkers int) *Dispatcher {
    pool := make(chan chan Job, maxWorkers)
    return &Dispatcher{WorkerPool: pool, MaxWorkers: maxWorkers}
}

func (d *Dispatcher) Run() {
    // starting n number of workers
    for i := 0; i < d.MaxWorkers; i++ {
        worker := NewWorker(d.WorkerPool)
        worker.Start()
    }

    go d.dispatch()
}

func (d *Dispatcher) dispatch() {
    for {
        select {
        case job := <-JobQueue:
            // a job request has been received
            go func(job Job) {
                // try to obtain a worker job channel that is available.
                // this will block until a worker is idle
                jobChannel := <-d.WorkerPool

                // dispatch the job to the worker job channel
                jobChannel <- job
            }(job)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    dispatcher := NewDispatcher(MaxWorker)
    dispatcher.Run()
    JobQueue = make(chan Job)

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        work := Job{FileIndex: i}

        // Push the work onto the queue.
        JobQueue <- work
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("done in %s", elapsed)
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 0, write file done in 11.838574ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 2, write file done in 19.516134ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 1, write file done in 14.525345ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 3, write file done in 15.714428ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 4, write file done in 14.858648ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 6, write file done in 13.567686ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 5, write file done in 13.952953ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 8, write file done in 12.848465ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 7, write file done in 16.949355ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 10, write file done in 18.237936ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 9, write file done in 14.750701ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 11, write file done in 15.03977ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 12, write file done in 14.320434ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 14, write file done in 16.248813ms
2022/10/03 11:54:53 goroutine id: 13, write file done in 15.655994ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 16, write file done in 13.760309ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 15, write file done in 14.58592ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 18, write file done in 15.343521ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 17, write file done in 15.035341ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 20, write file done in 14.53919ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 19, write file done in 14.59754ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 22, write file done in 14.190191ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 21, write file done in 14.810599ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 24, write file done in 14.843376ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 23, write file done in 15.578197ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 26, write file done in 15.244726ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 25, write file done in 14.845854ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 27, write file done in 14.719713ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 28, write file done in 15.499384ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 goroutine id: 29, write file done in 15.203875ms
2022/10/03 11:54:54 done in 241.901091ms
```

If someone can give a clear explanation that would be great

Comment: You're probably IO-limited. In general, disks (including SSD) can only execute one operation at a time, so you parallel operations are being serialized by the OS.

Comment: I guess but in other languages like JS for example, I don't remember having this problem, how could I enable parallelism then in Go ?

Comment: There's no parallelism to enable. If you are IO-limited, there's no switch to flip to make the disk work faster.

Comment: sure, but it seems weird that I'm blocked by 30requests when I have an SSD NVMe, I would think it's more the program I wrote at fault here

Comment: Also: math/rand.Read serialises all calls. Try pregenerating your random data before writing.

Comment: ok @Volker I'll try that, but my original problem happens without this random data, even if I write a simple buffer, I get the same results (with different time) but time is increasing

Comment: @Volker still the same thing when pregenerating the data

Comment: Or use a separate `rand` source instance for each goroutine. But you're writing writing 225MB of data in 276ms, that's 810MBps. Depending on the drive and other activity, IO limitation is a possibility even on NVMe.

Comment: @Adrian it's the same behaviour if use a slice with 5 bytes, it's not about the amount of data unfortunately

Comment: Interesting, that doesn't sound like IO limitation then. I'd be curious to see how much of the execution time is consumed by the file creations as opposed to the actual data writing. Have you profiled your code to see where it's taking time?

Comment: I haven't run a profiler, I'll try that

Comment: https://anopic.us/Rlw1KoEsWOObRKmHrGklTuOENlrnkouMGpni8WOz.jpg

Comment: https://anopic.us/eE74WupDdDzDHXybvBpqAZZOy44JYnSLllYlXkSp.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Go does write to the disk in parallel. The reason of the sequential behavior in the question is `math/rand`. This package uses *thread safe* random number generator that is implemented with internal mutex: see [`Read`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/math/rand/rand.go;drc=8e35910640bd190103d99d994d54b738e619c858;l=364), [`globalRnd`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/math/rand/rand.go;drc=d7dbe0111ef2a6de80a20fef188db61d8fab5c96;l=298) and [`lockedSource`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/math/rand/rand.go;drc=d7dbe0111ef2a6de80a20fef188db61d8fab5c96;l=385)

That's why your `GenerateFile` goroutines run almost strictly one by one - they synchronyze internally on `rand.globalRnd.lk` mutex.

There are two ways to improve performance. One is to use independent PRNG in each thread and another one is to pre-generate data for write.

Here is a sample program that tries all variants.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

const N = 30

var elapsed_g [N]time.Duration

func SortAndLogElapsed(prefix string) {
    sort.Slice(elapsed_g[:], func(i, j int) bool { return elapsed_g[i].Nanoseconds() < int64(elapsed_g[j].Nanoseconds()) })
    for _, elapsed := range elapsed_g {
        fmt.Println(prefix, elapsed)
    }
}

func GenerateFile(start time.Time, id int) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    buf := make([]byte, 7500000)
    rand.Read(buf) // generate random data
    randomFileName := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/gotest-%v", rand.Int())
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(randomFileName, buf, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.Remove(randomFileName)
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    // log.Printf("generate file %s done in %s", randomFileName, elapsed)
    elapsed_g[id] = elapsed
    return nil
}

func RunWithCommonPrng() {
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go GenerateFile(start, i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    SortAndLogElapsed("common PRNG: ")
    log.Printf("done in %s", elapsed)
}

func GenerateFilePrivatePrng(id int, prng rand.Source, start time.Time) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    buf := make([]byte, 7500000)
    rand.New(prng).Read(buf) // generate random data
    randomFileName := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/gotest-%v", prng.Int63())
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(randomFileName, buf, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.Remove(randomFileName)
    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    elapsed_g[id] = elapsed
    // log.Printf("generate file %s with private source: done in %s", randomFileName, elapsed)
    return nil
}

func RunWithPrivatePrng() {
    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go GenerateFilePrivatePrng(i, rand.NewSource(int64(i)), start)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    SortAndLogElapsed("Private PRNG: ")
    log.Printf("done in %s", elapsed)
}

func GenerateFileWithGivenData(id int, buf []byte, start time.Time) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    randomFileName := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/gotest-%v", rand.Int())
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(randomFileName, buf, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.Remove(randomFileName)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    elapsed_g[id] = elapsed
    // log.Printf("generate file %s with data: done in %s", randomFileName, elapsed)
    return nil
}

func RunWithCommonData() {
    buf := make([]byte, 7500000)
    rand.Read(buf) // generate random data

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go GenerateFileWithGivenData(i, buf, start)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    SortAndLogElapsed("Common data: ")
    log.Printf("done in %s", elapsed)
}

func main() {
    log.Printf("Used CPUs / Max CPUs: %d/%d", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0), runtime.NumCPU())

    RunWithCommonPrng()
    RunWithPrivatePrng()
    RunWithCommonData()
}
```

The output on 8-core CPU with SSD is like this:

```
2022/10/02 00:00:08 Used CPUs / Max CPUs: 8/8
common PRNG:  9.943335ms
common PRNG:  15.12122ms
common PRNG:  20.856216ms
common PRNG:  26.636462ms
common PRNG:  32.041066ms
common PRNG:  37.450744ms
common PRNG:  43.286644ms
common PRNG:  48.695199ms
common PRNG:  54.518533ms
common PRNG:  59.858065ms
common PRNG:  65.620084ms
common PRNG:  71.111171ms
common PRNG:  76.388583ms
common PRNG:  81.609326ms
common PRNG:  87.465878ms
common PRNG:  92.623557ms
common PRNG:  98.35468ms
common PRNG:  103.606529ms
common PRNG:  109.28623ms
common PRNG:  114.981873ms
common PRNG:  120.26626ms
common PRNG:  125.530811ms
common PRNG:  131.222195ms
common PRNG:  136.399946ms
common PRNG:  142.305635ms
common PRNG:  147.687525ms
common PRNG:  153.002392ms
common PRNG:  158.769948ms
common PRNG:  164.241503ms
common PRNG:  169.531355ms
2022/10/02 00:00:08 done in 170.273377ms
Private PRNG:  16.255543ms
Private PRNG:  17.155624ms
Private PRNG:  17.477437ms
Private PRNG:  17.49527ms
Private PRNG:  17.521759ms
Private PRNG:  18.363554ms
Private PRNG:  19.800906ms
Private PRNG:  30.340522ms
Private PRNG:  31.551496ms
Private PRNG:  40.583626ms
Private PRNG:  54.682705ms
Private PRNG:  54.832006ms
Private PRNG:  54.983126ms
Private PRNG:  55.143073ms
Private PRNG:  56.517272ms
Private PRNG:  56.577967ms
Private PRNG:  57.718ms
Private PRNG:  58.770033ms
Private PRNG:  59.246808ms
Private PRNG:  59.608246ms
Private PRNG:  59.789123ms
Private PRNG:  60.028814ms
Private PRNG:  68.533662ms
Private PRNG:  69.606317ms
Private PRNG:  69.837988ms
Private PRNG:  71.488161ms
Private PRNG:  71.770842ms
Private PRNG:  72.036881ms
Private PRNG:  72.23509ms
Private PRNG:  73.037337ms
2022/10/02 00:00:08 done in 73.694825ms
Common data:  5.220506ms
Common data:  5.220523ms
Common data:  5.220524ms
Common data:  5.220526ms
Common data:  5.221125ms
Common data:  5.221169ms
Common data:  5.222472ms
Common data:  6.977304ms
Common data:  13.601358ms
Common data:  13.614532ms
Common data:  13.859067ms
Common data:  14.75378ms
Common data:  16.00253ms
Common data:  16.111086ms
Common data:  16.263291ms
Common data:  16.42076ms
Common data:  17.024946ms
Common data:  17.313631ms
Common data:  17.749351ms
Common data:  18.18497ms
Common data:  18.83511ms
Common data:  21.789867ms
Common data:  22.308659ms
Common data:  22.308701ms
Common data:  22.546815ms
Common data:  23.298865ms
Common data:  23.482138ms
Common data:  23.610855ms
Common data:  23.667347ms
Common data:  24.500486ms
2022/10/02 00:00:08 done in 25.205652ms
```

"Common data" is for pre-generated buffer. It shows that Golang does write to disk in parallel. It distributes the goroutines between threads and those goroutines occupy CPU cores until I/O finishes.

**UPDATE**

Here is code that prints Linux thread ID and CPU number.

```
package main

/*
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/pkg/profile"
)

func GetCpu() int {
    var ret C.int = C.sched_getcpu()
    return int(ret)
}

func GetThreadId() int {
    return syscall.Gettid()
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

const N = 30

var elapsed_g [N]time.Duration

func SortAndLogElapsed(prefix string) {
    sort.Slice(elapsed_g[:], func(i, j int) bool { return elapsed_g[i].Nanoseconds() < int64(elapsed_g[j].Nanoseconds()) })
    for _, elapsed := range elapsed_g {
        fmt.Println(prefix, elapsed)
    }
}

func GenerateFileWithGivenData(id int, buf []byte, start time.Time) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    randomFileName := fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/gotest-%v", rand.Int())
    tid := GetThreadId()
    cpu := GetCpu()

    before := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("Before WriteFile:\t----\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", id, tid, cpu, before.String())
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(randomFileName, buf, 0666)
    after := time.Now()
    tid = GetThreadId()
    cpu = GetCpu()
    fmt.Printf("After WriteFile:\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", after.Sub(before).Microseconds(), id, tid, cpu, after.String())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.Remove(randomFileName)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    elapsed_g[id] = elapsed
    // log.Printf("generate file %s with data: done in %s", randomFileName, elapsed)
    return nil
}

func RunWithCommonData() {
    buf := make([]byte, 7500000)
    rand.Read(buf) // generate random data
    fmt.Printf("                \tElapsed\tG\tTID\tCPU\ttime\n")

    start := time.Now()
    println("")
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go GenerateFileWithGivenData(i, buf, start)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    SortAndLogElapsed("Common data: ")
    log.Printf("done in %s", elapsed)
}

func main() {

    log.Printf("Used CPUs / Max CPUs: %d/%d", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0), runtime.NumCPU())

    // RunWithCommonPrng()
    // RunWithPrivatePrng()
    defer profile.Start(profile.CPUProfile).Stop()
    RunWithCommonData()
}
```

The output on my system is (G internal goroutine ID, TID - Linux thread id, CPU - CPU number, last column is elapsed time) sorted by time:

```
                  Elapsed    G  TID     CPU     time
Before WriteFile:   ----    29  23379   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.35247545 +0900 KST m=+0.006016977
Before WriteFile:   ----    0   23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.352475589 +0900 KST m=+0.006017128
Before WriteFile:   ----    14  23383   7   2022-10-03 20:24:47.352506383 +0900 KST m=+0.006047950
Before WriteFile:   ----    7   23381   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.352572666 +0900 KST m=+0.006114235
Before WriteFile:   ----    10  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.352634156 +0900 KST m=+0.006175692
Before WriteFile:   ----    8   23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.352727575 +0900 KST m=+0.006269119
Before WriteFile:   ----    9   23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.352766795 +0900 KST m=+0.006308348
After WriteFile:    4133    14  23383   7   2022-10-03 20:24:47.356640341 +0900 KST m=+0.010181880
After WriteFile:    4952    7   23381   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357525386 +0900 KST m=+0.011066917
After WriteFile:    5049    29  23379   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357525403 +0900 KST m=+0.011066934
After WriteFile:    4758    9   23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.3575254 +0900 KST m=+0.011066928
After WriteFile:    4892    10  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357526773 +0900 KST m=+0.011068303
After WriteFile:    5051    0   23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.35752678 +0900 KST m=+0.011068311
After WriteFile:    4801    8   23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357529101 +0900 KST m=+0.011070629
Before WriteFile:   ----    12  23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357554923 +0900 KST m=+0.011096462
Before WriteFile:   ----    13  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357555161 +0900 KST m=+0.011096695
Before WriteFile:   ----    1   23381   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357555163 +0900 KST m=+0.011096697
Before WriteFile:   ----    2   23381   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.35756292 +0900 KST m=+0.011104452
Before WriteFile:   ----    11  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.3575642 +0900 KST m=+0.011105730
Before WriteFile:   ----    21  23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357570038 +0900 KST m=+0.011111568
Before WriteFile:   ----    25  23383   7   2022-10-03 20:24:47.357572217 +0900 KST m=+0.011113747
Before WriteFile:   ----    26  23379   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.358768915 +0900 KST m=+0.012310542
Before WriteFile:   ----    27  23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.361560776 +0900 KST m=+0.015102306
After WriteFile:    4020    25  23383   7   2022-10-03 20:24:47.361593063 +0900 KST m=+0.015134592
After WriteFile:    4873    12  23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362428015 +0900 KST m=+0.015969540
After WriteFile:    4858    21  23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362428103 +0900 KST m=+0.015969632
After WriteFile:    4865    2   23381   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362428238 +0900 KST m=+0.015969769
After WriteFile:    4864    11  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362428347 +0900 KST m=+0.015969877
Before WriteFile:   ----    15  23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362454039 +0900 KST m=+0.015995570
Before WriteFile:   ----    28  23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362454041 +0900 KST m=+0.015995573
Before WriteFile:   ----    23  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362454121 +0900 KST m=+0.015995651
Before WriteFile:   ----    16  23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362462845 +0900 KST m=+0.016004374
Before WriteFile:   ----    22  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.362479715 +0900 KST m=+0.016021242
After WriteFile:    4902    26  23379   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.363671623 +0900 KST m=+0.017213150
Before WriteFile:   ----    18  23386   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.365182522 +0900 KST m=+0.018724057
After WriteFile:    8764    13  23383   7   2022-10-03 20:24:47.366320071 +0900 KST m=+0.019861611
Before WriteFile:   ----    17  23379   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.366374805 +0900 KST m=+0.019916338
After WriteFile:    4902    27  23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.366463028 +0900 KST m=+0.020004556
After WriteFile:    4729    28  23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.367183315 +0900 KST m=+0.020724852
After WriteFile:    4720    16  23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.367183317 +0900 KST m=+0.020724850
Before WriteFile:   ----    19  23385   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.367230069 +0900 KST m=+0.020771602
Before WriteFile:   ----    20  23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.367748633 +0900 KST m=+0.021290163
Before WriteFile:   ----    3   23391   3   2022-10-03 20:24:47.368046383 +0900 KST m=+0.021587923
Before WriteFile:   ----    5   23388   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.36857915 +0900 KST m=+0.022120682
Before WriteFile:   ----    4   23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.368590097 +0900 KST m=+0.022131628
Before WriteFile:   ----    6   23393   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.370493582 +0900 KST m=+0.024035118
After WriteFile:    10260   22  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.372740578 +0900 KST m=+0.026282112
After WriteFile:    5326    20  23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.37307519 +0900 KST m=+0.026616720
After WriteFile:    10922   23  23387   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.373376163 +0900 KST m=+0.026917695
After WriteFile:    5613    3   23391   3   2022-10-03 20:24:47.373660058 +0900 KST m=+0.027201605
After WriteFile:    5332    4   23380   1   2022-10-03 20:24:47.373922339 +0900 KST m=+0.027463865
After WriteFile:    8871    18  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.374053982 +0900 KST m=+0.027595513
After WriteFile:    7880    17  23384   4   2022-10-03 20:24:47.374255159 +0900 KST m=+0.027796694
After WriteFile:    12127   15  23387   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.37458126 +0900 KST m=+0.028122790
After WriteFile:    7422    19  23391   3   2022-10-03 20:24:47.374652483 +0900 KST m=+0.028194020
Before WriteFile:   ----    24  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.375338247 +0900 KST m=+0.028879777
After WriteFile:    5111    6   23393   2   2022-10-03 20:24:47.375605341 +0900 KST m=+0.029146871
After WriteFile:    19459   1   23392   5   2022-10-03 20:24:47.377014458 +0900 KST m=+0.030555986
After WriteFile:    3847    24  23377   6   2022-10-03 20:24:47.379185393 +0900 KST m=+0.032726920
After WriteFile:    10778   5   23388   0   2022-10-03 20:24:47.379358058 +0900 KST m=+0.032899584
```

It shows that goroutines run in many differen threads on all cores of my 8-core CPU. It looks like the fastest IO is in those goroutines that preserved their thread and CPU. And it seems that parking/unparking threads make blocking IO slower.

I ran the same code with 100 goroutines. The worst case was as big as 60 ms, but it wasn't the last one, one in the middle. And even at the end there were fast writes with 5.5 ms time.

Comment: That's not solving the problem, as you can see with common data, for sure it's faster than when generating random data for each goroutine, but the time is still increasing, it's the same behaviour no matter the amount of data generated or not, it really boils down to the file writer. What I would expect is each call taking roughly the same time, and some faster than the previous one. It shouldn't be a linear time increase.

Comment: I understand that goroutine are started in parallel but sill the file writing has a sequential behaviour

Comment: @Pat-rice, I ran it under profiler: 71.43% of cpu time was spent in `syscall.write` and 28.57% in `syscall.unlinkat`. My understanding is that it is the Linux Kernel who to blame for not-so-parallel writes.

Comment: It's linked to the way golang manages OS threads, one thread is shared by multiple goroutines
https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoSchedulerAndSyscalls

Comment: @Pat-rice I added code that tracks CPU and thread usage. It seems to me that parking-unparking makes the thins slower at the end. At the beginning all IO runs at the same time without migrating goroutines between threads and cores.

Comment: ok I accept your answer since you gave me some good insight on thread and CPU usage by goroutine, but still later calls takes longer to perform the whole write than the first ones. I think it's best to use channel to avoid overloading the scheduler and get consistent results (See my Edit3 of my answer)